# How to Get user location Coordinates in android using GPS

Tags: android, coordinates, userlocation

i am new to locations, i want to ask that how can i get user current or last known location using GPS. i am using GoogleAPIClient. I am using google Map in my application in which i want to get User location in MapActivity and show it on map.

Comment: You can look for LocationListener and LocationManager

Comment: I have checked LocationListener and LocationManager but i havent understand that

Comment: If you look Location Manager examples, you will see example GPS apps after learning finding the location you can use google maps api to pinpoint the location by marker